# java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: 2017-10-29 of type java.time.LocalDate

Tags: java, javafx, datepicker

I am trying to save date from a datePicker into a mysql table as a String.I created the datePicker using Javafx Scene builder however when i try to save the date in the format of a String it returns this this error :

**java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 2017-10-29 of type java.time.LocalDate**

[image]

At first i want to add the input data from the user into an observable list then show it in a table to the user. Afterwards i want to insert the observable list data into the mysql database once the user has completed adding the relevant data they want.

I would like to add datePicker data into an observable list in the form of a String.

My question is how do i change the value of a date picker into a string and pass it into an observable list. In my code i used **.getEditor().getText()** but it throws the above error.

My datePickers are labeled

```
     fromDateCreateTask
     toDateCreateTask
```

The datatype of the T_startDate and T_endDate columns in the database is varchar(50).

This is my code :

```
void addTaskToTable(){


    AllTaskData.add(new Task(
            Integer.parseInt(taskNumberCreateTask.getText()),
            taskNameCreateTask.getText(),
            getProjectId(projectSelectedCombobox.getValue()),
            taskStatusCreateTask.getText(),taskInformationCreateTask.getText(), 
            (String) teamHeadComboBoxCreateTask.getValue(),
            fromDateCreateTask.getEditor().getText(),
            toDateCreateTask.getEditor().getText(),
            timeSpan()));
     createTaskTable.setItems(AllTaskData);

    taskNameCreateTask.clear();
    fromDateCreateTask.getEditor().clear();
    toDateCreateTask.getEditor().clear();
    teamHeadComboBoxCreateTask.setValue("Team Lead");
    taskInformationCreateTask.clear();
    taskCount++;

    taskNumberCreateTask.setText(Integer.valueOf(getTotalNumberOfTasks() + 1+taskCount).toString());

}
```

Adding to mysql table :

```
public void createMultipleTasks() {

    String sql = " insert into Task (T_id, T_name, P_projectCode, T_status, T_Description, T_lead,T_startDate,T_endDate,T_timespan)"
            + " values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {

        for(Task userTasks: AllTaskData){

        int taskNumber = userTasks.getTaskNumber();
        String taskName = userTasks.getTaskName();
        String taskStatus = userTasks.getTaskStatus();
        String taskDescription = userTasks.getTaskInformation();
        String teamLead = userTasks.getTaskTeamMemberAssigned();
        String startingDate = userTasks.getTaskFromDate();
        String endingingDate = userTasks.getTaskToDate();
        int taskcompletionTime = userTasks.getTaskTimeSpan();
        int projectId = userTasks.getProjectCode();//getProjectId(projectSelectedCombobox.getValue());



        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setInt(1, taskNumber);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, taskName);
        preparedStatement.setInt(3, projectId);
        preparedStatement.setString(4, taskStatus);
        preparedStatement.setString(5, taskDescription);
        preparedStatement.setString(6, teamLead);
        preparedStatement.setString(7, startingDate);
        preparedStatement.setString(8,endingingDate);
        preparedStatement.setInt(9, taskcompletionTime);

        try{
        preparedStatement.execute();
        }catch (Exception e) {
                DBConnection.infoBox("Error Saving Data", "Fail", null);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            try {
             DBConnection.infoBox("Click ok to cancel this message", "Sucess", "Saving of tasks has been successfull");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                DBConnection.infoBox("Error Unable to Open View", "Fail", null);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        DBConnection.infoBox("Error Saving Data", "Fail", null);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

calling the function :

```
    @FXML
void handleAddNewTaskAction(ActionEvent event) {

    if (taskNameCreateTask.getText()==null || taskNameCreateTask.getText()==" " || taskNameCreateTask.getText().isEmpty() ||
        fromDateCreateTask.getValue() == null || toDateCreateTask.getValue() == null ||
        teamHeadComboBoxCreateTask.getValue() == null || teamHeadComboBoxCreateTask.getValue().isEmpty() || teamHeadComboBoxCreateTask.getValue() == "Team Lead" ||
        taskInformationCreateTask.getText() == null || taskInformationCreateTask.getText().isEmpty() || taskInformationCreateTask.getText() == " "
            ){
      DBConnection.infoBox("Please enter text in missing fields", "Error Adding Data", "nil");
    }else{

    addTaskToTable();

    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the schema of the task table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use java.sql.Date or java.sql.Timestamp while working with DB dates. Please refer below.

```
public class JavaDateExceptionResolver {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    dateIssueResolverType1("2017-10-29");
    dateIssueResolverType2("2017-10-29");
}

private static Date dateIssueResolverType1(String input) throws ParseException {

    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.util.Date dt=sdf.parse(input);
    java.sql.Date sqlDate=new java.sql.Date(dt.getTime());
    System.out.println(sqlDate);
    return sqlDate;
 }

private static Timestamp dateIssueResolverType2(String input) throws ParseException {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    java.sql.Timestamp stmp=new java.sql.Timestamp(sdf.parse(input).getTime());
    System.out.println(stmp);
    return stmp;
}       
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer however i updated the question since it seems somewhat unclear. I would like to save the datePicker value as a string to an observable list first then save the observable list data in the mysql database.

Comment: Which data types are your columns T_startDate and T_endDate on the db?

Comment: they are varchar(50)

Comment: the error comes when i try to add  fromDateCreateTask and toDateCreateTask to the observable list.

Comment: Are you able to get the values from the variables fromDateCreateTask and toDateCreateTask?. If so are they like 2017-10-29. If yes then what is the datatype in which your Datatype of those variables? And what is the DataType of the Observable List.